# MySQL Stored Function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in mySQL Workbench.  The goal is to clean-up/standardize a field that reside in ad hoc tables that get loaded.  Here is a snippet of the code....many many Update lines missing.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Address`(TBL VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

SET @table_name = TBL;

UPDATE table_name SET AD1 = REPLACE(AD1,"P.O. BOX ","BOX ");
UPDATE table_name SET AD1 = REPLACE(AD1,"POBOX ","BOX ");
UPDATE table_name SET AD1 = REPLACE(AD1,"P O BOX ","BOX ");

END
```

---

Issue:  The function is NOT recognizing the table.

Error Code:

> 146 'kalo.table_name' does not exist

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name SET AD1 = REPLACE(AD1,"P.O. BOX ","BOX ");
       ^--missing @
```

You cannot use vars to replace SQL keywords/identifiers anyways, even if you had remembered to put the `@` there. You'll need to use dynamic SQL, e.g. build the query string manually, then `exec` that string. There's no other way to convert your `@table_name` string into an actual identifier.

Comment: please post the full create from procedure

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to put the Query in a variable and excute it as prepared statement

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Address`(TBL VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

SET @table_name = TBL;

SELECT CONCAT( "UMDATE ",@table_name, " SET ....") INTO @SQL;
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
-- next update
-- ...
END
```

Comment: This makes sense but now getting syntax errors probably because of the double quotes used in the CONCAT conflicting with my replace double quotes.  SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE ",@table_name," SET AD1 = REPLACE(AD1,"PO BX ","BOX ")") INTO SQL;

Comment: You also can put the SET ... in single quote like **CONCAT( "UPDATE ",@table_name, ' SET AD1 = REPLACE(AD1,"P.O. BOX ","BOX ")')**

Comment: Getting close.  I did a slight modification to what you gave me to include the library.  When I exclude the IN SQL I am getting a syntax error...so I excluded it and MySQL Workbench accepted it.  When I run the function I get an Error 1064 You have an error in your sql syntax.  check the manual for details.  The GUI does show the function code and how the concat looks.  When I open the version of concat as it is shown in the view...I swipe it...then paste it into sql screen it runs.  Something is going on with the IN SQL; aspect.  Right?

Comment: I meant to say INTO SQL, not IN SQL

Comment: I think I got this to work now.  Give me about 30 minutes to QC